# Using os.Lstat return value in Go

Tags: go

https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Lstat says :

```
func Lstat(name string) (FileInfo, error)
```

> Lstat returns a FileInfo describing the named file. If the file is a symbolic link, the returned FileInfo describes the symbolic link. Lstat makes no attempt to follow the link. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

However, the returned [os.FileInfo](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) interface does not make any symbolic link information available. Where does that information go? Should I use the platform-specific Sys() method on the `os.FileInfo`?

Comment: What information do you want from the link? Check `os.Readlink` maybe?

Comment: But then what’s the point of lstat?

Comment: lstat returns information about the symlink itself. Imagine a symlink like a file that just contains a string that points to another file. You can inspect that symlink file, or you can read its contents and follow to the other file. The os does this transparently for symlinks in stat, so lstat is for when you _don't_ want to automatically follow. This has been simplified a bit but maybe will give you a better idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Stat` returns info about the target file, `Lstat` returns the info about the symlink itself.

The info is all contained within the file's mode bits. You can use the predefined constants in the `os` package to check for the mode types you're interested in.

For example, if you pass `fileInfo` from `os.Stat("/path/to/symlink")` to the following code, it will *NOT* say it's a symlink. However, if you pass the return value of `os.Lstat`, it will:

```
if fileInfo.Mode()&os.ModeSymlink != 0 {
    fmt.Println(fileInfo.Name(), "is a symlink")
}
```

Comment: But that bit is returned in regular Stat, too. I feel like Lstat() returns important stuff like link’s target path, but go doesn’t make it available.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google: I'm not sure I understand. These follow the same conventions as the POSIX syscalls, `stat` returns info about the target file, `lstat` returns the info about the symlink itself. What part of those syscalls doesn't Go make available?

Comment: Thanks for the important bit. I'm editing your answer slightly to make it clearer. I had to write some code to realize `os.Stat` doesn't give you a way to tell the path is a symlink at all. https://play.golang.org/p/RpMpwLyyWo8